# Convert symbols to bits java

Tags: java, converters, symbols, bit

I need to convert symbols to bits so that every 2 symbols = 1 byte = 8 bits.
For example, if user input is `RR` then there should be `00001100` as result. (just an example)

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: what on earth is "a symbol"? you mean a text character? And what would be the rationale to map-umap `'RR' <-> 00001100` ?

Comment: It was just example. Yes I need to convert every 2 symbols to its hexademical format

Comment: did you consider to use map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood your question, there're two options to resolve then: The easy or the hard way.

Easy:

- First of all, you need know if the literal to be used is a hexademical value.
- You can create a Sorted map that's represent the ASCII table, using the key 0-9 | A-H and the value represent your binary number.

Example:

```
SortedMap<Character, String>
lo_binary = new TreeMap<Character, String>();
lo_binary.put('0', "0000");
lo_binary.put('1', "0001");
lo_binary.put('2', "0010");
lo_binary.put('3', "0011");
lo_binary.put('4', "0100");
lo_binary.put('5', "0101");
lo_binary.put('6', "0110");
lo_binary.put('7', "0111");
lo_binary.put('8', "1000");
lo_binary.put('9', "1001");
lo_binary.put('A', "1010");
lo_binary.put('B', "1011");
lo_binary.put('C', "1100");
lo_binary.put('D', "1101");
lo_binary.put('E', "1110");
lo_binary.put('F', "1111");
```

- Read the two symbols and try find your binary code into Sorted Map.
- Stores the result into a String

  String ls_symbols = "AA";
  String ls_result = " ";

  for (int ln=0; ln < ls_symbols.lenght(); ln++) {
     ls_result += lo_binary.get(ls_symbols.charAt(ln));
  }

  System.out.println(ls_result); // AA -> 10101010

Hard:

- First of all, you need know if the literal to be used is a hexademical value.
- Converts a literal with hexadecimal characters to byte[].
- Converts the byte[] to boolean[]
- The result is true = 1 and false = 0

Example:

// Do you have a literal A. This literal represents in binary the value 1010. Do you have // use the operator >>> and & to change the binary value to boolean value

```
1010
boolean = (1010 & 1000) == 1000 // (1000 = represents 0x80)
boolean = true (1);

1010 >>> 0100
boolean = (0100 & 1000) == 0000
boolean = false (0);

0100 >>> 1000
boolean = (1000 & 1000) == 1000
boolean = true (1);

1000 >>> 0000
boolean = (0000 & 1000) == 0000
boolean = false (0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand you. Why RR should be 00001100? In Hexadecimal 1100 represents the character 'C'.

Comment: It was just example. Yes I need to convert every 2 symbols to its hexademical format

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing because you talk of hexadecimal and then show binary numbers. Anyway, maybe this will help ... this converts an input to hexadecimal. Maybe you can use it to work out exactly what you need (which isn't that clear to me).

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "RR";       
        System.out.println(toHex(input));     

    }   

    public static String toHex(String arg) {
        return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes()));
    }    
}
```